# c# Resource (resx) Inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using resources on my *asp.net* application and need to make the key/value pairs available on the client. I have been able to get them there for a particular ***resource file*** by using an HttpHandler, but the standard inheritances are not working with the code I am using.

---

Base *PM.resx* file contains the following

```
key: a value: AAAAAA
key: b value: BBBBBB
key: c value: CCCCCC
```

---

*PM.pt.resx* file contains the following

```
key: a value: ptptpt
```

---

When I have a culture of `pt` on my browser or coded, I expect to get the following returned since the `pt` file only has a single entry in it and the base file contains the rest of the key/value pairs.

```
key: a value: ptptpt
key: b value: BBBBBB
key: c value: CCCCCC
```

But I am only getting the following.

```
key: a value: ptptpt
```

---

The c# code that I am using to generate the JavaScript is as follows.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Resources.PM", System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");//for testing culture change
        //ResourceSet resourceSet = rm.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
        ResourceSet resourceSet = rm.GetResourceSet(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, true, true);

        string r = string.Empty;

        if (resourceSet != null)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
            {
                string resourceKey = entry.Key.ToString();
                object resource = entry.Value.ToString();
                r += "\"" + entry.Key.ToString() + "\": \"" + entry.Value.ToString() + "\", ";
            }
        }

        r = "var q = {" + r + " culture: \"" + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() + "\"};";
        r += "console.log(q);$.each(q, function(k, v){console.log(k + \": \" + v)});";
        context.Response.Write(r);
    }
```

How can I get the inheritance to work in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a solution to my question. I created two `ResourceSets`; one for the default language (for the default resource) and another for the current language (for the language specific resource). I then created a `dictionary` of strings and first added the language specific key / value pairs, then the default key / value pairs. If there is a language specific key already existing, then the default language one will not be added.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string responseString = string.Empty;
        CultureInfo currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;

        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Resources.PM", System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));

        CultureInfo defaultCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

        ResourceSet currentRS = rm.GetResourceSet(currentCulture, true, true);
        ResourceSet defaultRS = null;

        if (defaultCulture != currentCulture)
        {
            defaultRS = rm.GetResourceSet(defaultCulture, true, true);
        }

        Dictionary<string, string> translations = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (currentRS != null)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in currentRS)
            {
                try {
                    translations.Add(entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception e) { }
            }
        }

        if (defaultRS != null)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in defaultRS)
            {
                try {
                    translations.Add(entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception e){}
            }
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> entry in translations)
        {
            responseString += "\"" + entry.Key.ToString() + "\": \"" + entry.Value.ToString() + "\", ";
        }

        responseString = "var translations = {" + responseString + " culture: \"" + currentCulture.ToString() + "\"};";
        context.Response.Write(responseString);

        Compress(context);
        //SetHeadersAndCache(absolutePath, context);
    }
```

Note: I did not illustrate escaping my key and value pairs here. This is something that I have to follow-up on in my code.

I hope this helps someone else down the line!